# Heat equation with initial condition $f(x)=\sin(2\pi x)-\sin(5\pi x)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Given the following heat equation problem
$$u_{t}=u_{xx},\quad u(0,t)=u(1,t)=0,\quad u(x,0)=\sin(2\pi x)-\sin(5\pi x)$$
when I calculate
$$c_{n}=2\int_{0}^{1}(\sin(2\pi x)-\sin(5\pi x))\sin(n\pi x)dx=0$$
I get
$$u(x,t)=0$$
what's wrong here?

Comment: You shouldn't get zero out of the integral for $n=2$ or $n=5$.

Comment: Always check that a denominator is not zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ A_n = \dfrac{\left<  \sin(n\pi x),\sin(2\pi x) - \sin(5\pi x) \right>}{\left<  \sin(n\pi x , \sin(n\pi x)\right>} $$

$$ \int_0^1 \sin^2(n\pi x) \mathrm{d}x  = \dfrac{ 2\pi n - \sin(2\pi n)}{4\pi n} = \dfrac{1}{2} \ , \ \sin(2\pi n) = 0 \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}  $$

$$ \int_0^1 \sin(n\pi x) ( \sin(2\pi x) - \sin(5\pi x) )\mathrm{d}x = \frac{7 \, {\left(n^{2} - 10\right)} \sin\left(\pi n\right)}{100 \, \pi + \pi n^{4} - 29 \, \pi n^{2}}$$

But considers $ h(x) = 100 \, \pi + \pi x^{4} - 29 \, \pi x^{2} \ , \ h(x) = 0 \iff x=-5 , x=-2, x=2, x=5 $ then $ 100 \, \pi + \pi n^{4} - 29 \, \pi n^{2} \ = 0  \iff n=2 , n=5$

Therefore $A_n = 0 \hspace{0.5cm} \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \backslash \{ 2,5 \} $

Then

$$ \int_0^1 \sin(2\pi x) ( \sin(2\pi x) - \sin(5\pi x) )\mathrm{d}x = \dfrac{1}{2}$$

$$ \int_0^1 \sin(5\pi x) ( \sin(2\pi x) - \sin(5\pi x) )\mathrm{d}x = \dfrac{-1}{2}$$

$$ A_2  = 1 \ , \ A_5 = -1$$

$$ u(x,t) = e^{-4\pi^2t} \ \sin(2\pi x) - e^{-25\pi^2t} \ \sin(5\pi x) $$

Comment: Tip: write `\sin` in the future.